# Loading Drop-DownList from session and save it to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I would like to know how to load the session data from a grid and pass it to next page of the 
drop-down list and save it in DB.

Eg: My grid data in page-1 Name,Address,Country

```
protected void PassData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gr = ((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);

        Session["Name"] = gr.Cells[3].Text.Trim();
        Session["Address"] = gr.Cells[4].Text.Trim();
        Session["Country"] = gr.Cells[5].Text.Trim();
   }
```

I was about to load the Country value  in Country Drop-Down list in page-2.
My drop-Down List have the pre loaded country list, I have to load the country value that 
i have in my Session["Country"].
eg:

```
CountryID  Country
   1       USA
   2       AUSTRALIA
   3       CHINA
```

so i used the code..

```
ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text = Session["Country"].ToString();
```

**In my page load the country list gets load**

```
private void BindCountry()
    {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = objUser.SelAllCountry();

            objCommon.BindDropDown(ddlCountry, "CountryID", "CountryName", dt);

            ddlCountry.SelectedValue = "1";        

    }
```

> ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text=My session value is present in it, but
>   cant able to store it in My DB..

```
int country 
objCustomer.Country = int.Parse(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);//state to pass the country value.. i know its wrong i need help over here to save my data.
```

I'm Unable to save the new value it always lodes the default value 1 USA
**Page Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindCountry();
            //BindState(1);
        }
}
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue..
Thanks-In advance..

Comment: Show us your Page_load() event code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is you are binding dropdown list in `page_load()`, try putting the binding code in `!IsPostback` condition block.

EDIT

Try setting selected index with below syntax.

```
ddlCountry.SelectedIndex = ddlCountry.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(Session["Country"].ToString()));
```

The above should be replaced to below line

```
ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text = Session["Country"].ToString();
```

Comment: actually i'm using it in !IsPostback

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the first value in your function **BindCountry()**..Avoid selecting that..

```
private void BindCountry()
    {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = objUser.SelAllCountry();
            objCommon.BindDropDown(ddlCountry, "CountryID", "CountryName", dt);
    }
```

Avoid this line..`ddlCountry.SelectedValue = "1";`

Comment: Are you binding the dropdown in the pageload?

Comment: Please post your page load event?

Comment: Please pass the id of the country in session and use ddlCountry.Selectedvalue=session["id"].tostring();

Comment: After executing this line - ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text = Session["Country"].ToString(); -did your dropdown select the particular country?

Comment: my drop-down set the value as AUSTRALIA but cant able to save.. if i save, it save the 1st value.